# Find all theorems in a long LaTeX document

Tags: regex, latex

I've got a LaTeX document which looks something like this:

```
Now, we go onto the following theorem:

\theorem{$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.}{Blah blah blah...}

\remark{This proof is often attributed to Hippasus of Metapontum.}

We can prove a more general result:

\theorem{For $n$ a non-square integer, $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.}{Blah blah blah...}
```

I want to match everything that looks like `\theoremnoname{Something 1}{Something 2}` and, in particular, get the parts `Something 1` and `Something 2` as distinct parts of the matching.

The difficultly arises in having an unknown number of `{`s and `}`s within the parts, and trying to get them to match up.

I've tried the regex `\theorem\{([^{}]+)\}(\{([^{}]*(\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*)\})` (i.e. making the parts greedy) but it's returning no matches.

Comment: This is better done with a LaTeX parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you can assume that whole `theorem` command is in a single line, the pattern `}{` does not appear inside the first group, and there are no brackets after the `\theorem{...}{...}` command at the end of the line (which is all true for your example text and reasonable for a decent latex document), the regexp `\\theorem\{(.*)\}\{(.*)\}` should work.

I think your regexp prefix `\theorem\{([^{}]+)\}...` is wrong, this indeed will not match anything as `\t` tries to match tab (so use `\\` instead). But even after that your regexp will just get to the first opening `{` as `[^{}]`matches only characters different from `{` and `}`, and fail to match the found opening `{` against the closing `}`.

I could use simply grep and put the parts into two files like this:

```
cat your-doc.tex | grep -oE '\\theorem\{.*\}\{' | cut -c10- | rev | cut -c3- | rev > first.txt
cat your-doc.tex | grep -oE '\\theorem\{.*\}' | grep -oE '\}\{.*' | cut -c3- | rev | cut -c2- | rev > second.txt
```

This gives you the following on your example text:

```
> cat first.txt
$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
For $n$ a non-square integer, $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.

> cat second.txt
Blah blah blah...
Blah blah blah...
```